# Software used for video animation gif

Tags: animation, illustration, gif

Can anyone suggest what software might have been used to make this video animation?

https://dribbble.com/shots/1912589-G-M?list=searches&offset=62

I see its been made into a gif so assume this excludes canvas/ html5 or flash, most likely 3d software to video to gif... Any ideas which software?
Thanks, phil

Comment: It's impossible to say for sure, but I'd guess AfterEffects

Comment: [Here's a tutorial of something similar to your example done in AE](http://youtu.be/JgwTO0-qDJ4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the gif format excludes flash, becouse it can be exported as an animated gif.

You need to more methodical.

**Step 1)** Create the animation.

**Step 2)** Generate an animated gif as an output.

For both steps are many programs and methods, but the leader on this kind of motion graphics is after effects. It also can be done in flash.

Although it can be done in manual process in photoshop or simmilar, including vector programs, I don't think it has.

The step 2 part is easy, either the program exports it directly or you simply transform a video format (or still images) to animated gif.